# How to convert feet and inches into inches using classic .asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have thousands of different sizes that I need to convert from feet and inches into inches using classic .asp.

The sizes are listed in the following format:

```
[width] x [height]
```

The width and height are shown with ' marks, which stand for feet and " marks which stand for inches.

For example, take the following and convert it into inches:

```
2'6" x 8' = width = 30; height = 96
9'6" x 13'6" = width = 120; height = 162
```

Sometimes there is no X in the size, indicating that it is round or square in shape. For example:

```
2'6"
```

That would have to make both the width and height the same, so:

```
2'6" = width = 30; height = 30
```

Sometimes, there is a trailing " at the end, where there should be inches, but there are none listed. For example:

```
5'0" x 8'" = width = 60; height = 96
```

I am guessing that I would need to create some sort of custom function with expressions, but just having a hard time figuring it out.

I tried creating the following function, but it only outputs the test size I created, 5' x 4'

```
'example source sizes
'5'2" X 4'3"
'4' X 3'
'3'4"
'5'
'23" X 21"
'21"

'then run the function
'idsize = GetInches(rs("size"))
dim idsize
idsize = "5' x 4'"
GetInches(idsize)
Response.Write (idsize)

Function    GetInches(feet_inches)
    dim sizehold 
    feet_inches = split(feet_inches,"X")
    sizehold = split(feet_inches(0),"'")
    feet_inches = sizehold(0)
    feet_inches = replace(feet_inches,chr(34),"")
    feet_inches = replace(feet_inches,"'","")
    feet_inches = trim(feet_inches)
    feet_inches = feet_inches * 12
End Function
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: yeah, create function with several expressions and let it do its job

Comment: If your having a hard time show us what you have so far and we will try and fill in the blanks.

Comment: Ok.  I just added some sample code above.  Still stuck on how to parse it out efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to search the string for an X and then use string split functions.

You can split on the X if it exists to start to split things out into the width and height. You should then be able to split on the single quote, convert the feet using *12 and add to the inches.

Remember that classic ASP is basically VB script so there's probably some code for this floating around on google.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  This is the closest thing I could find, but it seems fairly complicated for what I want to accomplish:
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/excel/310996-text-parsing-splitting-string-feet-inches.html